# Why isn't my dispatch working? React Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, redux, firebase-authentication

I´m trying to change my firebase username using the redux store.

I have a register form that receive the email, password and username of the input and then the form create a firebase account with email and password, then I update the displayName using **updateProfile** of firebase. See this

That´s my redux reducer:

```
case "CHANGE_USERNAME":
      const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

      currentUser.updateProfile({ displayName: state.user.displayName });

      return { ...state.user, displayName: action.payload };
```

This is the store:

```
const initialState = {
  logged: null,
  user: {}
};
```

And this is part of my register form:

```
firebase
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
        .then(() => {
          this.props.dispatch({
            type: "CHANGE_USERNAME",
            payload: { ...this.state.username }
          });

          alert("Account created!");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // Handling errors
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          alert(errorCode);
        });
```

Why the username is not changing?

Comment: is either of this alerts `alert("Account created!");` `alert(errorCode);` working?
if not  this function `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` not return `Promise`

Comment: Yeah, I receive Account created!, the bad thing is that the promise don´t change my Redux store

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything from your promise.  Assuming that `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` returns a promise, and that the response contains a `username` field, you want to dispatch `response.username` to your reducer.

```
    .then((response) => {
      this.props.dispatch({
        type: "CHANGE_USERNAME",
        payload: { response.username }
      });

      alert("Account created!");
    })
```

In your reducer, you want to add the new `username` state.  Something like:

```
return { ...this.state, username: payload }
```

Comment: It´s impossible that this work because i not receive username from the firebase promise, I have the username in the state of the component

Comment: Bro, I think the problem it´s not the form. See, I tried do to this:

case "CHANGE_USERNAME":
      alert(action.payload);
      const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

      currentUser.updateProfile({ displayName: state.user.displayName });

      return { ...state.user, displayName: action.payload };

And I receive my username

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all, I had fixed the problem using:

```
case "CHANGE_USERNAME": {
      const currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;

      currentUser.updateProfile({ displayName: action.payload });

      return {
        ...state,
        user: { ...currentUser.providerData[0] }
      };
    }
```

At my reducer and:

```
this.props.dispatch({
      type: "CHANGE_USERNAME",
      payload: this.state.displayName
    });
```

At my dispatch, thanks!